# Spring boot Junit tests fail : I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8080/v1/pr": Failed to connect to localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8080

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, junit

I am writing Junits for my spring boot code.  I am unable to mock and test RestTemplate.
I went with SpringBootTest as an integration test approach instead of simple unit test, as the resttemplate was not getting initialized:

This is my client layer:

```
@Component
class PromoClient(
    @Autowired private val restTemplate: RestTemplate) {

    @Value("\${billing.url}")
    private lateinit var billingUrl: String

    fun getPromotion(): PromotionsDTO {
        val response = restTemplate.getForEntity<PromotionsDTO>(billingUrl)
        return response.body?: throw IOException("No Promocode available")
    }

}
```

Trying these Junits which are failing:

```
import com.ninjasquad.springmockk.MockkBean
import com.zoox.maestro.pricing.webapp.util.PromotionsDTO
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.Mockito.anyString
import org.mockito.Mockito.`when`
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.getForEntity
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.test.context.TestConstructor
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate
import java.net.URI

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@TestConstructor(autowireMode = TestConstructor.AutowireMode.ALL)
class PromoClientTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var promoClient: PromoClient

    @Mock
    private lateinit var restTemplate: TestRestTemplate

    @Bean
    open fun restTemplate(): TestRestTemplate {
        return TestRestTemplate()
    }

    @Test
    fun testGetPromotion() {
        val billingUrl = "https://example.com/promotions"
        val expectedPromotion = PromotionsDTO("TEST PROMO")
        // Mock the behavior of RestTemplate
        `when`(restTemplate.getForEntity<PromotionsDTO>(anyString(),any()))
            .thenReturn(ResponseEntity(expectedPromotion, HttpStatus.OK))
        // Test the getPromotion method
        val result = promoClient.getPromotion()
        // Assert the result
        assertEquals(expectedPromotion, result)
    }

}
```

The error is:

```
I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8080/v1/pr": Failed to connect to localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8080
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8080/v1/pr": Failed to connect to localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8080
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Expecting the test cases to pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your *PromoClient* you're autowiring a *RestTemplate* but inside your test you just initialize a *TestRestTemplate*.
Reading the [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/web/client/TestRestTemplate.html) of *TestRestTemplate* it says:

> Note: To prevent injection problems this class intentionally does not extend RestTemplate. If you need access to the underlying RestTemplate use getRestTemplate().

This means that your *TestRestTemplate* will never be injected into your *PromoClient*.
For testing a client using a *RestTemplate* you may want to use the [@RestClientTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.autoconfigured-rest-client) annotation. This would require you to inject the *RestClientBuilder* inside your *PromoClient* where you can just call *.build()* on to get your pre-configured *RestTemplate*.